# Почему numpy неверно считает определитель матрицы

Tags: python, numpy, линейная-алгебра

```
import numpy as np


A = np.array([[1, 1, 2, -1],
              [2, -1, 0, -5],
              [-1, -1, 0, -2],
              [6, 3, 4, -3]])

print(np.linalg.det(A))
```

Считаю таким образом. Определитель должен быть равен нулю, я проверял на бумажке и в онлайн калькуляторах. Но этот код дает такой ответ `5.329070518200744e-15`.
Что я делаю не так? Может где-то невнимателен был, а если нет, то каким образом лучше вычислять?

Comment: Потому что точность вычислений в компьютере ограничена. `5e-15` это очень близко к нулю, а получить ровно нуль скорее всего невозможно

Comment: У меня 0.0 вывел

Comment: У вас что за компутер?)

Comment: @Александр дэээ, не знаю как ответить на этот вопрос) Какие именно характеристики нужны? Процессор - интел кор 7 какой-то, ос - винда 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полагаю, что это может зависеть разве что от версий **Python** и особенно **Numpy**.
В **Google Colaboratory** выходит ровно **0.0**, даже если печатать 64 знака после запятой.
Я пробовал ставить разный тип данных (по умолчанию в этой матрице получается `numpy.int64`), например `numpy.int16` или `numpy.float32` - без разницы, всё-равно выходит **0.0**.
А вот `numpy.float16` выставить нельзя, на него `linalg` ругается, что с ним не работает.
Но проверьте ради интереса, какой у вас тип данных получается в матрице:

```
print(type(A[0,0]))
```

В **Google Colaboratory** такие версии стоят:

```
Python 3.6.9
Numpy 1.18.5
```

Код, которым я всё проверял:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 2, -1],
              [2, -1, 0, -5],
              [-1, -1, 0, -2],
              [6, 3, 4, -3]] #, dtype=np.float32)
            )

print(np.__version__)
print(type(A[0,0]))  
print(np.linalg.det(A))
print(f"{np.linalg.det(A):.64f}")
```

Результат:

```
1.18.5
<class 'numpy.int64'>
0.0
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Мой вывод для сравнения: Python 3.8.3 / 1.19.0 / <class 'numpy.int64'> / 5.329070518200744e-15 / 0.0000000000000053290705182007442942852850177296887944429124549239

Comment: @andreymal Опять они чтоли в новых версиях что-то испортили (  Поэтому обычно новые версии в промышленную среду сразу и не ставят, сначала тестируют как следует